# assertion failed while implementing getx dialog box on obx

Tags: flutter-web, flutter-getx

im trying to get the data fom the url string  and if the id is available it should navigate me to the another page it working fine but when i try to show Getx defaultdialogbox in the navigated page it shows Assertion failed

**this is my main page code**

```
`class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    navigate();
    super.initState();
  }

  void navigate() async {
    if (Uri.base.queryParameters["id"] != null) {
      controller.eid.value = Uri.base.queryParameters["id"]!;
      print(controller.eid.value);
      Get.to(Calendar());
    }
  }
```

**this is my navigated page**

```
class Calendar extends StatefulWidget {
  const Calendar({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _CalendarState createState() => _CalendarState();
}

class _CalendarState extends State<Calendar> {
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: FutureBuilder(
            future: controller.eventFetch(controller.eid.value),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                return CustomScrollView(
                  physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(
                      parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
                  slivers: <Widget>[
                    SliverAppBar(
                      snap: false,
                      pinned: true,
                      floating: false,
                      flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                          title: Text(controller.event.name!,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 16.0,
                              )), //Text
                          background: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              
                              Text(controller.event.slotDuration ?? ""),
                            ],
                          )),

                      expandedHeight: 230,
                      , //IconButton
                      ], //<Widget>[]
                    ), //SliverAppBar
                    SliverFillRemaining(
                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                          physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(
                              parent: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()),
                          child: Obx(
                            () => Column(
                              children: [
                                addVerticalSpace(10),
                                TableCalendar(
                                  
                                  eventLoader: _getEventsfromDay,

                                  //To style the Calendar
                                  
                                Wrap(
                                    spacing: 5.5,
                                    direction: Axis.horizontal,
                                    runSpacing: 6,
                                    children: _getEventsfromDay(
                                            controller.selectedDay.value)
                                        .map((slot) => AbsorbPointer(
                                              absorbing: !slot.available!,
                                              child: OutlinedButton(
                                                style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                                                  side: BorderSide(
                                                      color: Colors.green),
                                                  shadowColor: Colors.green,
                                                  surfaceTintColor:
                                                      Colors.green,
                                                  foregroundColor: Colors.green,
                                                ),
                                                onPressed: () {
                                                  Get.defaultDialog(
                                                      title: slot.id ?? "",
                                                      content: Text(slot.uid ??
                                                          "76776873786764"),
                                                      actions: [
                                                        TextButton(
                                                            onPressed: () {
                                                              controller.userBook(
                                                                  eventId:
                                                                      controller
                                                                          .event
                                                                          .id,
                                                                  
                                                                  uid:
                                                                      "2345678");
                                                            },
                                                            child: Text("Book"))
                                                      ]);
                                                },
                                                child: Text(
                                                  '${slot.startTime} - ${slot.endTime}',
                                                  
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ))
                                        .toList()),
                              ],
                            ),
                          )),
                    ),
                  ],
                );
              } else {
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
              ;
            }));
  }
}
```

im dont knwo what is happening but it show assertion failed.
Showing error as assertion failed when outlined button is pressed

Comment: what's that assertion ocntains, can you include it

Comment: the assertion error navigate me to the source code page and shows the code      void _pushEntry(_RouteEntry entry) {
    assert(!_debugLocked);
    assert(() {
      _debugLocked = true;
      return true;
    }());

Answer (score 0):

Routing, dialogs, bottom sheets, snack bar, context features provided from `Getx` requires changing `MaterialApp` to `GetMaterialApp` in your app.

Comment: im already using GetMaterialApp only